# What to we learn from וַיִּשַּׁק יַעֲקֹב לְרָחֵל?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, vayeitzei, jacob, rachel-imenu

The following is an (uncited) premise in learning torah that creates this question.  Every word of the torah is measured (there are no extra words) and therefore important.

In parshas Yeyeitzei (בראשית כט יא) it says וַיִּשַּׁק יַעֲקֹב לְרָחֵל.  What are we supposed to be learning from that? The statement raises a lot of questions (especially nowadays) and I couldn't find anything specific we learn from it. So why include it, (seemingly) the phrase could have been easily skipped.

All the meforshim seem to explain about the nature of the kiss and how it fits into the narrative are almost (for a lack of better phrase) justifications of the kiss. I couldn't find anywhere where it affects the narrative or gives a lesson, so why include it? The kiss just seems to raise questions .

Question: What lesson is contained in the words וַיִּשַּׁק יַעֲקֹב לְרָחֵל? What does it either add to the narrative or teach us?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for -- there are commentaries which explaiin the nature and type of kiss and how it fits in to the narrative. Are you asking if there is additional homiletic content that has been innovated?

Comment: I am asking more what was the purpose of including it.. all that it explains about the nature of the kiss and how it fits into the narrative are almost (for a lack of better phrase) justificaitons of the kiss. I couldn't find anywhere where it affects the narrative or gives a lesson, so why inlcude it? The kiss just seems to raise questions .

Comment: I see my question is unlcear based off my above comment is there anyway I can clarify my question?

Comment: There are certainly lessons and information that we can gain that go beyond the simple text https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.29.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi

Comment: I am commenting here because I am unsure where else to adress the fact that the question was closed. the referenced question only asks why it was permissible. I know why it was permissble, my questions is why is it important to inlcude to start with, what extra information is it adding?

Answer (score 2):

The root in Hebrew of the verb *to kiss* is נשק. This root has several different meanings which can be found in the Jastrow dictionary, such as:

1) to kiss (*with the mouth*)

2) to equip, meaning to supply or furnish or provide for

3) to cleanse or make ritually fit

This last meaning also has a connotation of *immersing in water* like in the case of a mikvah and also *watering* from השקה and להשקות.

And it is in context of these additional meanings that the commentary Tz'ror HaMor by [Rabbi Avraham Saba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Saba) to this parsha deals with the inner understanding of the text.

Rabbi Saba explains in connection with [Bereshit 29:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Tzror_HaMor_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.29.1.2?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) that through prophetic vision, Yaacov was aware of the extreme impurity of the place he was traveling to.

> אחר כך אמר וישא יעקב רגליו וילך ארצה בני קדם. הרצון בזה לפי שיעקב קודם המראה היה ירא מעשו ומלבן. לפי ששמע שהיה לבן רמאי גדול ומכשף גדול ולבן **היה מושבו בארץ קדם שהיא ארץ טמאה מלאה גלולים וכישופים.** ולכן אמרו רז"ל ולבני הפלגשים אשר לאברהם נתן אברהם מתנות. שמות הטומאה מסר להם וישלחם קדמה אל ארץ קדם מקום ראוי להם. כי שם נמצאו כל הכישופים. **כאומרו כי מלאו מקדם ומעוננים כפלשתים. ולכן היה יעקב מתירא מהם ולא היה רוצה ללכת שם.**

Rabbi Saba goes on to explain that in this context, one understanding of this parsha is addressing the final redemption through Moshiach and how that takes place.

> **ורז"ל גילו בכאן** מסתורים גדולים שהם כבשונו של עולם **בענין קץ משיחנו ועיכוב הגאולה. בסבת אבן הזאת הגדולה שהיא לב אבן.** הנם כתובים בספרי הזוהר ואינם בידי כי נגזל ממני בעונותי בגירוש פורטוגא"ל. **ונראה שזאת הפרשה קשורה עם של מעלה. ובכאן התחיל יעקב להשלים נפשו בשלימות האמתי.** והתחיל השם יתברך להשגיח עליו ולהשלים דברו. שנאמר והיה ה' לי לאלהים. שיהא נקרא אלהי יעקב כמו האבות. בענין שגם כן האבות יהיו המרכבה. ולכן אמר וירא והנה באר בשדה. **וזה הבאר היא אבן הראשה. האבן אשר שם מראשותיו משם רועה אבן ישראל.**

And he then explains that the great stone covering the well is the obstacles which were to be the cause for the future destruction of the first two Temples and that it also blocks the final redemption.

> ולהורות על שלימות יעקב. **הראהו שם שלשה עדרי צאן רובצים עליה. שהם גדולה גבורה תפארת. שהם כנגד אברהם יצחק יעקב.** בענין שיעקב חבל נחלתו והוא משולש בזכיות והוא רגל ראשון מהמרכבה. וזה וירא והנה באר בשדה. זהו שדה אשר ברכו ה' שאמר יצחק ליעקב. והיא באר שבע. ועליה יושבים שלשה עדרי צאן הם האבות. **והאבן גדולה על פי הבאר. היא אבן נגף וצור מכשול לשני בתי ישראל שנתן עיניו במקדש ראשון ובמקדש שני והחריבם.** וזהו סכות בענן לך מעבור תפלה. **וצריך סיוע וזכות אבות להסיר האבן מעל פי הבאר.** לפי שהיא סתומה וצריך שיאספו כל העדרים של מעלה ושל מטה להסיר האבן מעל פי הבאר. **וזהו סבת עיכוב גאולתינו בעונותינו.**

And the remedy for these obstacles to the redemption is the merit of the Avot and Imahot together with our learning the Torah.

> **ולכן צריך שנתעסק בתורה. ונשקה הצאן במי התורה. וזהו השקו הצאן.** והם השיבו לא נוכל עד אשר יאספו כל העדרים של מעלה ושל מטה להעביר האבן מעל פי הבאר. ואנו מחכים לאבן הראשה אבן ישראל שיבא לפוצץ סלעים. ולהסיר האבן הגדולה מעל פי הבאר. כאומרו בדניאל חזה הוית עד די איתגזירת אבן די לא בידין ומחת לצלמא על רגלוהי. **וזה יהיה בסיוע האבות והאמהות. ובפרט רחל שהיא עקרת הבית** צריכה להתחנן על בניה.

And Rabbi Saba then goes on to explain that this fourth and final redemption comes in particular through the merit of Yaacov and Rachel working together through their prayers and the words of Torah they speak. That this is the *watering of the flocks*.

> ו**זה שאמר ויהי כאשר ראה יעקב את רחל בת לבן אחי אמו. שהיא בוכה ומתאוננת על בניה. ויגש יעקב בתפלה ובתחנונים.** ויגל את האבן מעל פי הבאר. **לפי שלו משפט הגאולה לגאול בגלות רביעי. בענין שיבנה בית יעקב על מכונה. ולכן תמצא בגלות רביעי וזכרתי את בריתי יעקב וגו': והזכיר ליעקב בראשונה.** לפי שהוא בעל הקורה. **והוא לקח הוא"ו של אליהו והוסיפה על שמו למשכון שיבא לגאול את בניו. ולכן כתב יעקוב מלא בוא"ו. וכן רמז בכאן יעקוב מלא בוא"ו. וכן רמז בכאן שיבא אליהו לגאול את בני יעקב באלף הששי שאנו עומדים בו. ולכן נכתב מלא וא"ו.** וכן תמצא שכמו שבכתה רחל דכתיב רחל מבכה על בניה. כן בכה יעקב. ולזה אמר וישא את קולו ויבך כדכתיב קול על שפיים נשמע בכי תחנוני בני ישראל. **השם יתברך יראנו מתורתו נפלאות:**

And this leads to the answer to your question concerning what this *kiss of the mouth* is adding.

There are different levels within the Torah. And the innermost *secrets* of the Torah, the *wonders of the Torah* נפלאות התורה, what are called Kabbalah, Torat HaNavuah and Chassidut today, are referred to as the *kisses of the mouth*, like is found in connection with [Shir HaShirim 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.1.2?lang=bi) from King Solomon.

> **יִשָּׁקֵ֙נִי֙ מִנְּשִׁיק֣וֹת פִּ֔יהוּ** כִּֽי־טוֹבִ֥ים דֹּדֶ֖יךָ מִיָּֽיִן׃

And this is what Rabbi Saba goes on to express, that through the great love and yearning of Yaacov Avinu, he speaks these *wonders* together with Rachel. That Yaacov kisses Rachel in order to bring the fourth and final redemption.

> ואולי רמז **ויהי כאשר ראה יעקב את רחל. כי בראותו אותה חשקה נפשו בה.** **וידוע כי החושקים ואוהבים אשר אומרים שיעשו גבורות ונפלאות עד אין מספר.**

And this is in keeping with the adage that the final redemption comes through the merit of our learning the inner aspect of the Torah, the *Penimiyut HaTorah*.